# Getting the echoed contents of a PHP file from another PHP file

Tags: php

I am building a simple API, at `api.php`:

```
<?php echo "Hello, World" ?>
```

I'd also like to be able to access that API from a different file, `test.php`:

```
<?php echo "api.php contents: " . file_get_contents("api.php"); ?>
```

If I type the URL of `api.php` into the browser, it displays "Hello, World" as expected, but `test.php` does not display the results of `api.php`, but instead displays nothing, with the PHP code of `api.php` in commented HTML.

How would I go about getting the results of `api.php`directly from `test.php`?

Comment: If you want to **execute** the contents of `api.php` then you need to `include` or `require` it: `include "api.php";`.  This will cause the contents of the PHP file to be inlined at the position of the `include` statement.

Comment: I do not want to execute the code, I'd just like to get the returned contents of the code and be able to store them in a variable, manipulate the contents, etc.

Comment: Store the output from `file_get_contents` in a variable then instead of `echo`ing it.  I don't understand what other result you could have expected from the above code?

Comment: You don't want to execute code but you want to store, manipulate...

Comment: Well, PHP will not return you anything unless being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exec command like below,

```
echo "api.php contents: " . exec("php api.php");
```

[exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) — Execute an external program

file_get_contents won't evaluate php code. It just gets static content and will show it to it.

[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) — Reads entire file into a string